# How to add sub-options under options in select dropdown menu in react?

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, components

I am implementing a react app in which there is a dropdown menu with different options that are fetched from a dummy backend api using `json-server` I am able to add options but I need to add sub-options that are also fetched from api.

Here's my db.json Api structure:

```
{  
  "groups":[  
     {  
        "key":"version",
        "apis":["system_info","admin"]
     },
     {  
        "key":"admin",
        "apis":["patients","doctors"]
     },
    
  ]
}
```

In the above json respsonse `keys` are the options and all the strings under `apis` are to be sub-options.

Here's my Dropdown menu implementation:

```
import React from "react";

export default class ApiDropDown extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      options: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchOptions();
  }

  fetchOptions() {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/groups")
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        this.setState({ options: json });
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <select className="togglebutton" >
        <option selected disabled>Choose here</option>
          {this.state.options.map((option, key) => (
           
           <option key={key}>{option["key"]}</option>
           
           
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Api Response:

```
0: {key: "version", apis: Array(2)}
1: {key: "admin", apis: Array(2)}
```

This above dropdown is working for options but I need to implement sub-options.
Any idea how i can implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just fetch the suboption as you didn't for options. And use the below code for the sub option.

```
render() {
    return (
     <div >
      <select className="togglebutton" >
      <option selected disabled>Choose here</option>
        {this.state.options.map((option, key) => (
       
        <option key={key}>{option["key"]}</option>
         
         <optgroup label={option["key"]}>
            {this.state.subOptions.map((subOption, key) => (
              <option>{subOption.key}</option>
            ))}
             // OR

           {this.state.option["key"].subOptions.map((subOpt,i) => (
              <option>{subOpt.i}</option>
            ))}
           
         </optgroup>
   
       ))}
     </select>
   </div>
 );
}
```

Comment: Do i need to just add that <optgroup> body to make it work?

Comment: getting a error `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` by adding these lines

Comment: Yeah, It makes a group for nested select options.

Comment: For sub-option I had shared two approaches and you have to use them as per your data. So what approach you are using there?

Comment: 2nd one I am using

Comment: Can you share the HTTP response for your sub-options?

Comment: is there anything I need to add in suboptions?

Comment: I have added the response structure in the question,do i need to do another api call?

Comment: edited the question with the response i am getting with the fetch call

Comment: I don't see subOptions in it. How you are getting subOptions in it ?